# Sharing data between React elements through a Route

Tags: javascript, python, html, reactjs, flask

I am trying to exchange several data variables between multiple elements in React, essentially the equivalent of passing a pointer to a struct in C++ between various classes/functions

I am following this tutorial
https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components

I am using flask on backend to serve the /data route. This part works without issues.

However the error I get in console is `act-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: "activeState" is read-only`

How can I modify this code so that I can set `activeState` variable from within ToolbarElement?

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
function App() {

  activeState = {
    graph_data: 0,
    other_data: 1,
  }

  const [activeState, setActiveState] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-body">
        <div className="toolbar-element" style={{ top: "50px", left: "0px" }}>
          <ToolbarElement
            active_state={activeState}
            updateState={(state) => setActiveState(state)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="graph-element" style={{ top: "50px", right: "0px" }}>
          <GraphElement
            active_state={activeState}
            updateState={(state) => setActiveState(state)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

ToolbarElement.js

```
function ToolbarElement({
  active_state,
  updateState
}) {


  const [data, setdata] = useState({
    lst: [],
  });

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
    fetch("/data").then((res) =>
      res.json().then((data) => {
        // Setting a data from api
        setdata({
          lst: data,
        });
      })
    );
    active_state.graph_data = data.lst[0];
    updateState(active_state);
  };
  
  return (
    <div style={{ height: '33.33%', backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0' }}>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToolbarElement;
```

GraphElement.js

```
function GraphElement({
  active_state,
  updateState
}) {    

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '33.33%', backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8' }}>
      <p>{active_state.graph_data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GraphElement;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line here..

```
 active_state.graph_data = data.lst[0];
```

You are trying to mutate `active_state`.  You can not update state in react by mutating state. This line needs to be removed.

Instead you need to call the state setter you have defined.

```
setActiveState((prevState)=> ({...prevState, graph_data:data.lst[0]}))
```

I am using the functional method of updating state because you have an object as state.  So we are maintain the other values of the object by spreading `prevState`

something I just notices as well, you need to set your initial state like so..

```
    const [activeState, setActiveState] = useState({
      graph_data: 0,
      other_data: 1,
    });
```

and you should also remove the `activeState` object from `App`

---

Edit to refactor your code:

Update app to:

```
function App() {
  
  const [activeState, setActiveState] = useState({graph_data:0, 
  other_data:1});

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-body">
        <div className="toolbar-element" style={{ top: "50px", left: "0px" }}>
          <ToolbarElement
            setActiveState={setActiveState}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="graph-element" style={{ top: "50px", right: "0px" }}>
          <GraphElement
            active_state={activeState}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

update toolbar element to:

```
function ToolbarElement({
  setActiveState
}) {


  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
    fetch("/data").then((res) =>
      res.json().then((data) => {
        // Setting a data from api
        setActiveState((prevState)=> ({...prevState, 
         graphq_data:data[0]}))
      })
    );

  };
  
  return (
    <div style={{ height: '33.33%', backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0' }}>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToolbarElement;
```

upadate graph element to :

```
function GraphElement({
  active_state,
}) {    

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '33.33%', backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8' }}>
      <p>{active_state.graph_data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GraphElement;
```

Comment: If I remove the activeState object from App, where is it supposed to go?

Comment: Is is the state of `useState`.  You have `activeState` defined twice in `App`  Once as a plain object then below that as a returned value from `useState`.  We only want the returned value from useState

Comment: By this do you mean just declare it in app.js using    `const [activeState, setActiveState] = useState({
      graph_data: 0,
      other_data: 1,
    });` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited my previous comment to better reflect what I intended.

Comment: I have edited my response to refactor your components.  The toolbar component doesn't really need to be stateful, since it was just using state to update the parent state. The graph element doesn't need to have a state setter I removed it.  So now the state in `app` is maintaining state used by both children components, and toolbar is no longer stateful

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your 'handleButtonClick' callback. You've taken the existing state object and modified its `graph_data` property with:

```js
   active_state.graph_data = data.lst[0];
```

Instead you should simply call `updateState` with a new object for your state.

e.g.

```js
   updateState({ ...active_state, graph_data: data.lst[0] });
```

Comment: still getting the read only error

Comment: Then you didn't do what I suggested.